# Задача по JS нужно исправить ошибку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет я не прошу решить задачу а указать на ошибку, суть в том что когда в переменной "а" больше или равно 6 символов нужно вывести "1" но работает только else даже если больше чем шесть символов

```
function f7() {
    let a = document.querySelector('.i-7');
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-71');
    let out1 = document.querySelector('.out-72');

    out.innerHTML = a.value;
    if ( a.length >= 6) {
        out1.innerHTML = 1;
    }
    else {
        out1.innerHTML = 0;
    }

}

document.querySelector('.b-7').onclick = f7;
```

Comment: console.log(a.length)

Comment: `a.value.length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо писать  `if ( a.value.length >= 6) {` Потому что сейчас вы длину проверяете не у значения из инпута, а у элемента DOM